# What is the best way to increment invoice ID?

Tags: php, mysql, business-logic

I'm developing a simple invoice system using PHP and MySQL.
My initial thought was to use ID (auto incremented) for invoice ID. But that will not work.

A temporary invoice is created when user commits an order to my Payment Service Provider.
If the transaction fails, I need to delete the temporary invoice.

The problem is that the invoice has been created and given and ID - and by law, I'm not allowed to delete any invoices that has been given a invoice number. So I need to add another column 'invoice_id' and add an ID after successful transaction.

Multiple users may do a purchase at the same time.

My question is, how can I make sure to retrieve the last created invoice ID and increment this?

Should I use a `$_SESSION[]`for storing `invoice_id`? Or should I retrieve latest ID from DB? If retrieving from DB, should I lock the table for this transaction?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Comment: You should not insert records into your invoice table until the invoice has been raised (you can store quotes/estimates/proforma invoices in other tables prior to them becoming firm).  Once raised, it should *never* be deleted: if payment fails, or something else goes wrong, one might issue credit notes or other documents to rectify the situation or even cancel the invoice (without deleting it).

Comment: Ok, is this normal? Using two tables?

Comment: I would use one table with an `type` field (invoice/temp). I would not use the `auto_increment` as a invoice `id`. I would generate a custom invoice id like `<year>/<month><invoice count for that month>` (you can generate it with a simple date and count operation.

Comment: Ah, I just thought of something. I can just create a table having (id, invoice_id), and then the other table has (id, and all other fields). Once there has been done a successful transaction then I'll just add a row to the first table!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a temporary table for invoices which have not been processes.
Once the invoice has been processed, move over to permanent table and assign an invoice id using the AUTO_INCREMENT option in mysql

This will allow for two tables, one for unprocessed and the other for processed. You can also place an id field to keep track of the movement from temp -> perm

Comment: Thanks. I will do something simpler. Instead of having two identical tables, I will crate one table only having id and fk_invoice_id, where fk_invoice_id references the invoice table. So every successfull payment, I only need to add one row this new table.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't delete it, I would just cancel it. Additional usually after a failed transaction the trader reminds the customer to pay, which is not possible, when the invoice doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I don't think that is necessary since they will not get Premium online subscription unless they have completed a successful transaction (?).

Comment: @Steven OK, then I would just cancel it. This may help to keep track of unreliable customers too ;) and such things.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to keep the invoice in session until the payment has been approved.  If the payment is not approved, the invoice will die with the user's session.

Another approach would be to create a holding table for pending invoices.  When payment is approved, simply move the data into the invoice table.

And the last approach, go ahead and create the invoice in the invoice table, but soft delete it if the payment fails.  Just set a flag, deleted = 1 and in all your procs add "where deleted = 0".

Answer (score 0):

I would generate purely random invoice numbers. Simplest strategy:

```
md5(uniqid())
```

But still – storing unfinished invoices in the database sounds more sane.

Also the random factor will make guessing the invoice number more difficult.

Comment: Many jurisdictions require invoices to be numbered sequentially.

Comment: If this is for ordering purposes only then you can append the current timestamp to the string ID.

Comment: How does that help?  They still won't be sequentially numbered, which is often required so that tax auditors can satisfy themselves that they have seen every invoice raised in a given date range.